# osX : runLoop options (when creating event taps)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, macos, events

I am currently writing a piece of code which uses an event tap. It is working as it should, but I've got a few questions about some options that are not very well documented or that I'm not sure to understand 100% well. Most often when explained, the event tap procedures are quite given as "just do that" but with no further explanations, and I noticed some different possibilities, and the apple developer doc didn't enlighten me very much (so it's either too little or too much info at a time)... So :

---

```
CFMachPortRef machPortRef = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGTailAppendEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, eventTapCallback, NULL);
```

First line, no problem all is pretty clear.

---

```
//// -----> kCFAllocatorDefault or NULL ???         
CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, machPortRef, 0);
```

1) Here, I always saw that you should put `kCFAllocatorDefault`, but all the doc states is `"The allocator to use to allocate memory for the new object. Pass NULL or kCFAllocatorDefault to use the current default allocator."` So not being familiar with those allocators or other crocodiles, why would we pass `NULL` ??? I suppose `NULL` isn't a very efficient allocator... (that's quite a bonus question, just curiosity).

---

```
//// -----> CFRunLoopGetMain() or CFRunLoopGetCurrent() ??? 
CFRunLoopRef runLoop = CFRunLoopGetMain(); 
//CFRunLoopRef runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
```

2) What's the difference between getting the main loop with `CFRunLoopGetMain()` and the current loop with `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` ??? Which one is the best to use in which case ???

---

```
//// -----> kCFRunLoopCommonModes or kCFRunLoopDefaultMode 
CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
//CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

3) What's the difference between `kCFRunLoopCommonModes` and `kCFRunLoopDefaultMode` ??? From what I understood, `kCFRunLoopCommonModes` include the `kCFRunLoopDefaultMode`. So when do you use one or the other ???

---

```
CGEventTapEnable(machPortRef, true);
```

Don't forget to activate your tap hehe.

Thanks a lot by advance. I think these deserve some clear and concise explanations, that would be a great help and time saver for people getting into event taps.

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on these APIs. Were you just looking at the docs for event taps or did you look at the docs for `CFRunLoop`, too? [CFRunLoop Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corefoundation/reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html) [Related conceptual guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen the second one (the conceptual guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It doesn't matter. By passing `kCFAllocatorDefault` you explicitly select the default allocator, by passing `NULL` you implicitly select the default allocator. The system will not use `NULL` of course, but the default allocator.

Personally I make such things explicit, if I care about the default ("Yes, I need the default allocator") otherwise I use NULL ("Don't care, the system will do right.")

2) Every thread has a run loop attached. With `CFRunLoopGetMain()` you get the run loop of the main thread, with `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` you get the run loop of the thread, your code is currently running on. This is the same, if your code runs in main thread, otherwise a different run loop.

The main run loop on the main thread is automatically started as the main thread is automatically run.

You can add additional threads (with their own run loops) to your process. Usually you do not want to use the thread's run loop, because you do longer computations or so in the additional (background) thread. But sometimes you need the run loop in this background threads, if something is handled via run loop, i. e. networking.

3) Add a timer to the main run loop in default mode that writes out something every second and enter the menu with your mouse. You will see the difference …

The sources added to the default mode are only dispatched, when the run loop is in default mode, that means – to make a long story short – when the application is in an unmodal state. For example the menu or "local run loop dispatching" while drag & drop is not done in the default mode.

Simply think of modes as a group of sources. Every source in a mode is only dispatched, if the run loop runs in that mode. So it is a kind of selection of sources.

Sources in the common run loop mode are special, because they always dispatched independently of the mode.

Comment: It is not correct that "Sources in the common run loop mode are … always dispatched independently of the mode". The common mode**s** (plural) are in a set of modes. The system adds particular standard modes to the set of common modes. Your app can add its own modes to the set using `CFRunLoopAddCommonMode()`. Scheduling a source in the common modes is different from scheduling it in each of the modes in the set because the source will be automatically scheduled to a new mode that's added to the set of common modes, if/when that is done.

Comment: It is true, that you can have more than one run loop mode. But I do not get your point that this makes the statement incorrect, esp. in relation to the Q.

Comment: The relationship is complex, read the documentation to `CFRunLoopAddCommonMode()`. But don't care about it, you need custom common modes rarely. IIRC on the Cocoa layer there is always only one common mode – to show the relevance.

Comment: The statement is incorrect because it's not true that sources are dispatched independently of the mode. One can, for example, run a run loop in a custom mode. Assuming that custom mode is not in the set of common modes, a source added to the common modes would not fire. Adding a source to the common modes simply is **not** like some wildcard, such that it always fires.

Comment: Ok so I understood it well. Amin Negm-Awad did kind of a shortcut here, which was cool because that was the kind of answer I was asking for. Though, Ken Thomases, you're totally right to give that valuable precision. So thanks to both of you.